# PygLatin game - Help making alphabet of the word go to end

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to code this on codecademy.com , but due to some bug it it shows the lesson is completed. so I can't take a hint.

> Break It Down
> Now let's take what we've learned so far and write a Pig Latin translator.
>
> Pig Latin is a language game, where you move the first letter of the word to the end and add "ay." So "Python" becomes "ythonpay." To write a Pig Latin translator in Python, here are the steps we'll need to take:
>
> Ask the user to input a word in English.
> Make sure the user entered a valid word.
> Convert the word from English to Pig Latin.
> Display the translation result.

```
word=raw.input("Please enter a word: ")
if word.isalpha():
    print "Thanks the word is valid"
else
    print "Please enter a valid word"
x =len(word)
for m in range [0,x]
    word=word[1]+word[2]
```

so far I entered a word and checked if it is valid.

I was trying a loop but I failed .. but I haven't been taught the loop in codeacademy so I guess I have to achieve the pyglatin word without it.

I can't think of anything please help

Comment: Whats wrong with slicing? `s[1:]+s[0]+'ay'
`

Comment: the code is tried is
    word=raw_input("Please enter a word: ")
    if word.strip().isalpha():
        print "Thanks the word is valid"
    else:
        print "Please enter a valid word"
    x =len(word)
    for m in range [0,x]
        word=word[1]+word[2]

Answer (score 0):

```
word = raw_input ("give me a word: ")
if len(word) > 3 and word.isalpha():
    print word.lower() + " Pyg Latin: " + word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
else: 
    print "Try nex time, by!"
```

try this. It should give lohaAay for Aloha what is accordance with definition PygLatin.
In line 3 is clue : 
word.lower is printing lower cases original word. 
then we print " Pyg Latin: "

and now stright to target:

word[1:] - original word without first letter

word[0] - it is only first letter

"ay" that our tail.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = raw_input('tape :')
if a.isalpha():
    print  a[1:] + a[0] + 'ay'
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. It ask user to input an English word. It validates the word and confirms with a Thank you message (if the input is not an English word, it will post a message for that). It will then translates it to PygLatin by moving the first alphabet to last and adding ay in the end.

```
    pyg = 'ay'
word = raw_input ("Type a word: ").lower()
if word.isalpha():
    print "Thanks, the word is valid"
    first=word [0]
    new_word= word +first +pyg
    new_word= new_word[1:len(new_word)]
    print "The pyg_latin translation is: ",new_word
else:
     print "The word is not a valid english word"
```

Comment: Explain your answers please. "This should work" doesn't explain what the code is doing.